# How to run Locust on EC2 with Web UI

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, locust

I have used this article "https://medium.com/locust-io-experiments/locust-io-experiments-running-in-docker-cae3c7f9386e" to install Locust on the EC2 server as a Docker image.
It seems it works but when I try to view the Web UI it's not displaying at all.
Check the below screenshot for more info:
[image: 1]

Comment: You need to open the port 8089 in your EC2 Instance and access the page by its public IP

Comment: I did this I asked the IT guys to add the port to this server from the security group inside the inbound rules but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

burningalc is correct. The EC2 instance needs to have the ports accessible to whatever IP address you're connecting from (VPN addresses, if applicable, otherwise open to the public). You'd then use your web browser to hit the IP address of the instance at the port and you'd see the web UI. There's nothing else we can suggest you to do as that's how it works. If it's not working for you, either it's not configured properly or you're not connecting from the IP address the port is allowed on. You'll need to follow up with your IT guys, as you say.